# pagination in WP rest api

Tags: rest-api

We have made a custom API to get all the post in descending order and we want to add pagination in that API. I have read other questions and answers but didn't get the idea. Can anyone explain to me with a simple code with pagination so that I can understand how it works? The following is the code that I have done till now:

```
define('API_ENDPOINT_VERSION',1);

//flush the rewrite rules on plugin activation

function apiendpoint_activate()
{
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'apiendpoint_activate');

function apiendpoint_register_endpoints(){
    register_rest_route(
        'api/v1',
        '/post',
        [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' =>'api_get_post',
        ]
    );

}
add_action('rest_api_init','apiendpoint_register_endpoints');

function api_get_post($request){
    $ar = array( 'post_type'=>'post',
         'posts_per_page'=>15,
         'orderby' => 'date',
         'order' => 'DESC',
       );
    $posts = get_posts($ar);
    //var_dump($posts);
    //exit;
    $a = array();

    if($posts){
        foreach ($posts as $post) {


        $a[]= array(   
        'title'=>$post->post_title,
         'link'=>get_the_permalink($post->ID),
         'category'=>get_the_category($post->ID),
         'published_date'=>get_the_date('l, F j, Y',$post->ID),
          'guid'=>$post->guid,
          'image'=>get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID,'large'),
           'description'=>$post->post_excerpt,
           'source'=>"Nepaljapan"
        //'img'=>$img
        );
        }
        return $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a whole new endpoint just to get posts in descending order...

Comment: no no i made it custom bcause i want to make with its own key i mean value with my own key so cn you explain how can i add pagination

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: You could look at [WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_items()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.3/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L156) which does pagination for a posts query. It looks like it passes the page number from the query string as 'paged' in the options array. It also follows the usual WordPress REST API convention of adding X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages headers with the number of posts and pages respectively.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt and yes we have got the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
define('API_ENDPOINT_VERSION', 1);

//flush the rewrite rules on plugin activation

function apiendpoint_activate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(); } register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'apiendpoint_activate');

function apiendpoint_register_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route(
        'api/v1',
        '/post',
        [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'api_get_post',
        ]
    );

} add_action('rest_api_init', 'apiendpoint_register_endpoints');

function api_get_post($request) {
    $ar = array('post_type' => 'posts',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => ($_REQUEST['paged'] ? $_REQUEST['paged'] : 1) 
); 

$posts = get_posts($ar); //var_dump($posts); //exit; $a = array();

if ($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {


        $a[] = array(
            'title' => $post -> post_title,
            'link' => get_the_permalink($post -> ID),
            'category' => get_the_category($post -> ID),
            'published_date' => get_the_date('l, F j, Y', $post -> ID),
            'guid' => $post -> guid,
            'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post -> ID, 'large'),
            'description' => $post -> post_excerpt,
            'source' => "Nepaljapan"
            //'img'=>$img
        );
    }
    return $a; } 
}
```

Call API call as below:

/wp-json/api/v1/post?paged=1

Increase the paged value by 1 to get next paging posts.
This is the correct answer that we have got and has worked for me